# Recover BTC from seed

Tags: wallet

I wonder if you can help me.

I have my 17 word seed (yes 17 words) and my wallet crypto address and I can see my crypto on the blockchain under that address.

How do I restore my wallet with the above two things because my previous device failed and is dead.

Comment: Where did you get a 17 word phrase from? It’s not bip39 compatible, probably a proprietary algorithm

Answer (score 1):

There have been other questions about [17 word](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=17+word) phrases. It may be possible that they are legacy recovery phrases from obsolete wallet software provided by the business blockchain.info (now blockchain.com). That business has a [web page for wallet recovery using legacy phrases](https://login.blockchain.com/wallet/forgot-password).

> ### Mnemonic Phrase
>
> If you have a legacy wallet recovery mnemonic saved enter it below to view the password and login link.
> NOTE: If you have a 12 word recovery phrase from our HD wallet, please go to the HD wallet recovery page.

I would hate to put a recovery phrase into a website of some random business, but maybe you originally used that business for your wallet for some strange reason? If so, that may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on the issue, but try to find out what algorithm was used initially to generate your private key from those 17 words.

You should be able to apply the same algorithm and get it back.

I did not get from the question if your wallet was hardware or software, but either way, by checking the documentation of that wallet, you should be able to find the information above.

Hope this helps.